# SSIS : Error failed to acquire connection. Connection my not be configured correctly or you may not have right permission on this connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Development environment : Data tools 2017, SQL Server 2019.

We have developed one SSIS project, with a package that drops certain staging tables and recreates the same with changed structure. The same is working fine on a local machine. But problem comes when we try to run the same from a network machine using OLEDB native client with user name SA.

When we run the same script from SQL query from management studio, the query runs perfactly, still the task execution fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the type of connection that we were taking.

Comment: Consider adding more information about your solution and how you figured it out. As is this does not tell the reader what you did to solve your problem.